# How to import ES6 style modules in a WordPress environment?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm getting stuck using Modules in a WordPress environment. Mind you, this is the first time I'm working with Modules and I'm just trying to clean up my code and organize on my companies website.

I'm getting an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` using FireFox.

### Outline of issue:

I want to use functions from my `helpers.js` files in other files, like a `product.js` file. I'm using WordPress to enqueue them.

#### Enqueuing the files:

I have a `functions.php` file that enqueues the the module script, then appends the `type="module"` then enqueues my `product.js` file.

```
if (is_product()) {

   // Helper JS Module:
   wp_enqueue_script('helper-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/helpers.js', array('product-js'), $theme_version, true);

   //Imports Helpers.js as a module:
   add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_type_to_script', 10, 3);
   function add_type_to_script($tag, $handle, $source) {
       if ('helper-js' === $handle) {
           $tag = '<script src="' . $source . '" type="module" ></script>';
       }
       return $tag;
   }

   // Main Product JS
   wp_enqueue_script('product-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/product.js', array(), $theme_version, true);
}
```

#### ES6 Module:

In `helpers.js`:

```
const removeThisOption = (selectBox, optValue) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.length; ++i) {
    if (selectBox.options[i].value === optValue) {
      selectBox.classList.remove("validated");
      selectBox[i].remove();
    }
  }
};

export { removeThisOption };
```

#### Main Product file:

Lastly, I want to use the `removeThisOption` function above in other files, and I've tried to import it like so:

```
import { removeThisOption } from "./helpers.js";
```

However, I'm still getting the error. The product.js file is enqueuing after the module, and all files are loading correctly. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was adding the `type="module"` on the wrong file. I needed to add the module type on the file that I wanted to use the function in.